# jQuery DataTables server-side processing using JSP and JAVA

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am new to Jquery and Datatables. I am trying to use Datatables in my project. Can anyone please let me know get the data from JSP/Java and use it in Datatables.
Any links or examples would be very helpful.
Thanks
Bharath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are asking ajax based datasource to be used with datatables.

You can find some samples in the below links
[Server side processing](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)
[Ajax Source](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Documentation for [server side processing](http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side) can be found [here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side).

Comment: But this ain't specific to Java. Any sample code snippet for Java?

Answer (score 11):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359750/jQuery-DataTables-in-Java-Web-Applications) is an example of Datatables integrated with Java servlets/JSP . You can also download the source code with a working example.

Comment: Is there any new one with integrated V 1.10 of Datatable and may be using MongoDB @jovan MSFT